# Copy Maven dependency files and runtime in jpackage

Tags: javafx, jpackage

I have a JavaFX project with dependencies on `SQLite` and `POI`, so I used `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy all dependencies in `target\lib` folder. That folder contains about 21 dependencies `common-codecs, curvesapi, javafx-base, javafx-fxml...` etc.

To create a jpackage I'm using `jpackage-maven-plugin` to create an installer. I have `jmods` folder copied to `java.home`. The POM is as follows:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.39.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <launcher>App</launcher>
                    <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.panteleyev</groupId>
                <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <name>ExampleFX</name>
                    <appVersion>${project.version}</appVersion>
                    <icon>${basedir}/icon.ico</icon>
                    <vendor>Myself</vendor>
                    <destination>Runtime</destination>
                    <modulePaths>
                        <modulePath>C:\Program Files\Java\jmods</modulePath>
                        <modulePath>${project.build.directory}/classes</modulePath>
                    </modulePaths>
                    <module>com.example/com.example.App</module>
                    <runtimeImage>${java.home}/lib</runtimeImage>
                    <winDirChooser>true</winDirChooser>
                    <winShortcut>true</winShortcut>
                    <winConsole>true</winConsole>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>19</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This command neither packages the `lib` folder in the installer, nor does it properly copies JVM, as on running the program, it gives `Failed to find JVM in "C:\Program Files\Example\runtime" directory.` error. Any help appreciated.

*EDIT*

Changed some parameters:

from`<runtimeImage>${java.home}/lib</runtimeImage>` to `<runtimeImage>${java.home}</runtimeImage>`,

added module path `<modulePath>${project.build.directory}/lib</modulePath>`

Now the app fails to find modules (dependencies) which are present in `${INSTALLDIR}/app/mods`. Trying to add these modules require I remove `runtimeImage` parameter. If I do so:

```xml
<addModules>javafx.fxml,javafx.controls,
org.apache.poi.ooxml,org.apache.poi.poi,org.xerial.sqlitejdbc,SparseBitSet,
org.apache.commons.compress,org.apache.commons.codec,org.apache.commons.collections4,
org.apache.commons.io,com.github.virtuald.curvesapi,commons.math3,
org.apache.commons.collections4,org.apache.xmlbeans</addModules>
```

I always get error regarding any module randomly:
`jlink failed with: Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: commons.math3 from file:///C:/Users/MY/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Example/target/lib/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar`

**module-info**

```java
module com.example{
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.base;
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.apache.poi.poi;
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;
    requires org.apache.commons.codec;
    requires org.apache.commons.collections4;
    requires org.apache.commons.compress;
    requires org.apache.commons.io;
    requires commons.math3;
    requires com.github.virtuald.curvesapi;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires SparseBitSet;
    requires org.xerial.sqlitejdbc;
    requires org.apache.xmlbeans;
    
    opens com.example to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example;
}
```

Comment: I have used the [akman jpackage plugin](https://akman.github.io/jpackage-maven-plugin/) to package JavaFX apps successfully before.  I have not tried the panteleyev plugin.  So perhaps try the akman plugin.  I don’t have the example app definition anymore though to post an example of usage of the akman plugin.  I don’t recall needing to use the dependency plugin in conjunction with the akman plugin, but your project may be different then mine, requiring a different setup.  Also see JPackageScriptFX.

Comment: I tried using akman plugin too, but both have the same problem. I tried changing the parameters (check EDIT) and now the error is different.

Comment: @jewelsea is there any tutorial on how to use JPackageScriptFX? Their Readme is not beginner friendly at all.

Comment: I don’t know.  User mipa helped create the tool. Perhaps he has some advice.  But overall I expect not.  Packaging in this way is unfortunately not trivial and requires some work to get right.  It is, I think, likely to easier for completely modular apps (no automatic modules).  But unfortunately most apps have some non-modular dependencies and external config, as I guess yours does, which usually makes it overall more complicated.

Comment: And yeah, SparseBitSet is an automatic module (you can Google search to see what that is).  But it means jlink can’t link it.  It is just a limitation of the tool.  The library creators could fix it, I seem to recall a prior question where this came and one of the creators mentioned they wanted to fix it, but it was tricky.  jpackage and JPackageScriptFX can work with non modular libraries like that, but describing how to do that is not straightforward so out of scope for what I’d be prepared to discuss here. I can only refer you to the documentation for the respective tools and wish you luck.

Comment: I think for the automatic modules like SparseBitSet you must remove them from the module info and module path and instead load them from the classpath for the packaging and execution to work.

Comment: Your error message indicates you are using jlink, not jpackage.  jlink is a different tool and more strict about the dependencies being proper (non automatic) modules.

Comment: @jewelsea I think the plugin internally uses `jlink` and that too when I use the `<addModules> (--add-module)` flag. If I don't use that flag and simply use `<runtimeImage> (--add-runtime)`, then it bundles the exe successfully. However, on running the solution after installation throws error that modules javafx.fxml, sqlitejdbc etc not found and are required by App`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX). Here's how to use it:

(I'll refer to JPackageScriptFX as `JPS` and your project as `Example`)

1. Copy your Example project folder inside JPS's folder.
2. Open JPS's POM, and go to `<modules>` section. Remove all existing module entries (`jpackagefx-main,jpackagefx-module1,jpackagefx-module2`). Write `<module>Example</module>` instead.
3. Change `groupId` to Example's `groupId.artifactId`.
4. Open Example's POM. Write `<packaging>jar</packaging>` beneath `<version>` tag.
5. Copy `jpackagefx-main`'s maven-dependency-plugin from its POM and copy it to Example's POM.
6. Write `<configuration><mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass></configuration>` in javafx-maven-plugin if it isn't there already.
7. Copy whole of the `<profiles>` section from jpackagefx-main and copy it to Example's POM.
8. Rename `${client.version}` to `${project.version}` in `<APP_VERSION>` and `<PROJECT_VERSION>` (This is required especially in the case of Linux, otherwise the jpackage will fail in final stages (dpkg-deb returns with error code 2)).
9. Create a new class file named AppLauncher, and write following code in it:

```java
package com.example
public class AppLauncher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        App.main(args);
    }
}
```

10. Depending on your platform (Windows, Linux, Mac) copy the `build_app_linux.sh`, `build_app_mac.sh` or `build_app_windows.bat` file inside Example's project folder. I'll refer to the linux version in the next steps, you can find appropriate lines in other platform files.
11. Line 13, Change `MAIN_JAR="main-ui-...` to `MAIN_JAR="Example-...` or whatever the name of your Jar file is (You can find Jar filename by building the project and simply looking its name in `target` folder).
12. Line 47, change class path to `target/classes/com/Example/App.class`
13. Line 63, append modules you want in your project (in your case, `,java.sql`).
14. Line 92, Change to whatever name you want to give. You can also use quotes `"` to give space in the name.
15. Line 93, set --main-class to `com.example.AppLauncher`.
16. Line 97, optinally, set your own icon by modifying this line.
17. For Windows, additionally change line 40 to `--print-module-deps target\classes\com\example\App.class > temp.txt`.
18. Open pom.xml[parent] using Whatever IDE. I'm using netbeans, so I can clean and build the project by pressing SHIFT+F11.
19. If there's no error, then your installer will be present in `target\installer`